# Abort Previous Ajax requests using Ajax.BeginForm in C# MVC

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, ajax.beginform

I have an Ajax Form in a C# MVC webapp.
The users interactions on the page will automatically trigger some jQuery/javascript to submit the form.

```
$('#hiddenUpdateForm').submit();
```

The form I am submitting is in a codeblock:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "updatefunction(data)", }, new { id = "hiddenUpdateForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.Hidden("name");
    @Html.Hidden("value");
}
```

Is there any way to cancel/abort/terminate an ajax query using Ajax.BeginForm if a user triggers a new update before the original update results are returned to the browser?

Something similar to [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594) except preferably only using c#, not jQuery.
I am aware that the controller-action will still process the previous request however I need the users experience to be based on the most recent action they have triggered.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery